# Font, line spacing and format

Tags: fonts, formatting, document, line-spacing

I am trying to finish my final formatting for a thesis and the requirements are these:

- Page format: 21.5 x 28 cm (8.5" x 11”);
- Left-hand margin 3.81 cm (1.5"); other margins 2.54 cm (1");
- Line spacing 1.5 or 2, except where otherwise indicated;
- 12-point font in main body of text, unless otherwise specified;
- All pages numbered (except title page);
- No missing, blank, or duplicate pages;

I am wondering if the packages I am using and parameters would match the requirements (various packages are added for math tools as well). And what font type is the one using?:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[
style=authortitle,dashed=false,
sorting=anyt
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={21.5cm, 28cm}, tmargin=2.54cm, bmargin=2.54cm, lmargin=3.81 cm, rmargin=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{15pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{20pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

Expecting just corrections if necessary